# $\log \left(a^x\right)=x \log (a)$ and $-\log _x(2)=-\frac{1}{\log _2(x)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Since $a^x$ has domain $(-\infty ,\infty )$, $\log _a(x)$ has range $(-\infty ,\infty )$. Since $a^x$ has range $(0 ,\infty )$. Since $a^x$ and $\log _a(x)$ are inverse functions, the following cancellation identities hold:

$\log _a\left(a^x\right)=x$ and $a^{\log _a(x)}=x$

This is my reasoning:

$$\log _a\left(a^x\right)=x$$

$$\log _a\left(a^x\right)=x$$

$$\frac{\log \left(a^x\right)}{\log (a)}=x$$

$$\log \left(a^x\right)=x \log (a)$$

Now the last cancellation identity I don't understand ( $a^{\log _a(x)}=x$)

I also think that this is the reason why im not able to understand why

$$-\log _x(2)=-\frac{1}{\log _2(x)}$$

If someone could take the time to explain ( $a^{\log _a(x)}=x$) and $-\log _x(2)=-\frac{1}{\log _2(x)}$ It would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Logarithm is the inverse of the exponential function.  Also review change of base formula.

Comment: How did you define $\log_a x$ if not by the equation $a^{\log_a x}=x$?

Comment: It's not clear how you defined $\log_a x$, if not by the formula $a^{\log_a x}=x$. But you might have defined it as:

$$\log_a x = \frac{\ln x}{\ln a}$$ If you know that $e^{\ln x} = x$, then you can prove that $a^{\log_a x}=x$.

Answer (score 2):

In most precalculus courses I've seen, the logarithm is defined in terms of exponential functions in a statement analogous to: "$\log_ab = x$ means that $x$ is the number to which $a$ must be raised in order to obtain $b$". With this definition, your first identity becomes quite easy to understand. From the definition, the number $\log_a(a^x)$ should be the number to which we must raise $a$ in order to obtain $a^x$. But this is transparently $x$, so we have our answer.

Your second is a little more confusing. For instance, why bother with the negative signs? Leaving those out, you have:

$$\log_x2 = \frac{\log_22}{\log_2x} = \frac{1}{\log_2x}$$

This comes from the change of base formula and the fact that the $\log_aa = 1$. If you find this last identity at all puzzling please think very hard about it until it is obvious!

Comment: ($a^{\log _a(x)}=x$) in your answer as well then I do not need to wait for another answer